# What is this for? Df = pd.dataframe({"AAAA":[1,4,7]})

Tags: helper

I want to know what is that code for

I want to know what does it do please I need to know for what it is for. I want to find an answer please. Any help would be appreciated so please tell me what to do,to know the meaning. It is a little bit confusin, so please help me because I really want to know about that code